# dryer burn residue?

Tags: dryer, fire-hazard, laundry

I have this sort of burn residue in my dryer?

[image]

The question I have is:

1. Is this burn residue?
2. Is this a fire hazard?
3. How do I clean this off?

Also, much less important, is that I have some sort of blue color discoloration in this dryer:

[image]

How do I clean this off? Or if I can't, will this color stain my cloths?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Dryer heat source is: gas or electric?

Comment: dryer power sourse is electric. So I guess the heat source is also electric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) "Is this burn residue?"  It could be that the plating of the part reacted to heat or something being dried (ie. with a rubber backing) stuck to the part long enough to cause the marks.  On rare occasions there is an issue with the part's plating or the heat controls of the dryer.

Dryers shouldn't exceed 135-150 F.  Clogged vent exhaust flues are the most common reason for dryers to overheat.  Using a liquid fabric softener on 100% cotton (fleece, velour, terry-cloth) clothing is a potential reason for clothes to overheat (it also accelerates their burn speed).

2) "Is this a fire hazard?"  The residue itself, unlike creosote in a chimney, is not a fire hazard.  However, it could indicate a potential fire hazard (if the dryer's heat safeguards aren't working properly or the exhaust vent is clogged).  I would check the entire vent flue run for any blockage.  Then I would run the dryer and check the temp after about 10 mins.  Just open the door, quickly put in a baking thermometer (don't restart the dryer...it'll break the thermometer).  Assume of temp. drop of 10 F (add 10 F to the result).  It should be under 150 F (135 F is good).

3) "How do I clean this off?"  Unless it comes off using a damp cloth. I wouldn't bother trying to remove it.  If you're concerned about staining clothing, try wiping it with a damp cloth after checking the temp. (see #2 above).  If it still doesn't come off, it's not likely to come off onto clothes.

Re: Stain.

Test a bit of diluted bleach on a damp cloth.  If that doesn't take it off then it's not likely to cause stained clothing.  [Note: I'm guessing on this as I've not seen such staining before...that didn't come off with a bit of bleach...caused by new clothing dye run.]

Comment: Just to reiterate, in (2) you proposed to run the dryer. You mean run it empty right?

Comment: To clarify, to check the running temp, I would put in a couple dry bath towels upon which the thermometer could be set (to prevent the therm. from touching the sides of the dryer).

Answer (score 2):

The discoloration of the heat inlet is normal on Maytag/Whirlpool products.
https://producthelp.maytag.com/Troubleshooting_Guides/Troubleshooting_for_Dryers/Inlet_Grille_is_Discolored

The blue coloration is likely from blue jeans, and will not be a problem.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 2):

The burnt residue is normal but the burnt smell is not. Just be mindful if you smell something burnt from your dryer then something is wrong. To avoid your dryer from overheating, clean your filter regularly because it can get clogged and might overheat and damage the dryer. For the blue stain in your dryer, it might be discoloration or color transfer from clothes/jeans. Try wiping it with a damp cloth but if it doesn't come off, then it won't stain clothes.